# Способ найти сумму всех элементов в нескольких массивах

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив, который содержит в себе 9 массивов, в каждом из которых по 3 массива с 3 элементами(всегда числа).

Мне нужно посчитать сумму чисел в одном блоке(один блок - это массив, содержащий в себе 3 массива с 3 элементами в каждом) и, если она равна 45, вернуть `true`.

```
Arr=[Массив содержащий 9 блоков]
```

Один из блоков - `[ [5, 3, 4], [6, 7, 2], [1, 9, 8] ]` - нужно посчитать сумму элементов в каждом таком блоке, и вернуть `true`.

*Честно, не знаю как понятнее написать, или вставить сюда код, там очень много и без такого описания ничего не будет понятно.*

Comment: `[ [5, 3, 4],[6, 7, 2],[1, 9, 8] ].flat().reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Можно с помощью [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) сначала получить одномерный массив, а потом к нему применить [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), чтобы посчитать сумму и сравнить с нужным значением

   ```js
   const block = [
     [5, 3, 4],
     [6, 7, 2],
     [1, 9, 8]
   ];

   const isSumEqual = (block, value) => {
     return block
             .flat()
             .reduce((sum, num) => sum + num, 0) === value;
   }

   console.log(isSumEqual(block, 45));
   ```
2. Можно просто пройтись двойным циклом, посчитать сумму и сравнить с нужным значением

   ```js
   const block = [
     [5, 3, 4],
     [6, 7, 2],
     [1, 9, 8]
   ];

   const isSumEqual = (block, value) => {
     let sum = 0;
     
     for (const row of block) {
       for (const num of row) {
         sum += num;
       }
     }
     
     return sum === value;
   }

   console.log(isSumEqual(block, 45));
   ```